# PHP Form MySql Update Table with Foreign Keys

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, cmdb

I'm building a website that holds, laptop and customer information held in separate tables.
The structure of the **customer** table is;

```
ID, 
Name, 
Manager, 
Email
```

The structure of the laptops table is;

```
ID, 
Asset_No, 
Make, 
Model, 
RAM, 
CPU, 
MAC_Address, 
Serial_Number, 
Product_Number, 
User_ID, 
Location, 
Assigned, 
Faulty, 
Decommissioned, 
History
```

Where customer.ID == laptops.user_id

I have a separate page for displaying the laptops data, from updating the data.

On my update page, I want to be able to have a text field that pulls the customer.name and customer.ID data, into 2 separate fields, so that if i want to update the user assigned, I can use a  drop down field populated with user name, which will live update the value for customer.ID so that I can update the laptops.user_id field.
[update snip1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sM3B8.png)

[update snip2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sitZR.png)
[laptops display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcJVl.png)

Here is my updater page "update.php"

```
<?php
include 'functions.php';
$pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","appollo");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `category`";
$sql2 = "SELECT (Name) FROM bexstaff WHERE Name = ? ";
$sql3 = "Select Name FROM Customer ORDER BY Name Asc";
$sql4 = "Select ID FROM Customer ";
$all_categories = mysqli_query($con,$sql3);
$getIDs = mysqli_query($con,$sql4);

$msg = '';

if (isset($_GET['Asset_No'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        // This part is similar to the create.php, but instead we update a record and not insert
        $Asset_No = isset($_POST['Asset_No']) ? $_POST['Asset_No'] : '';
        $Make = isset($_POST['Make']) ? $_POST['Make'] : '';
        $Model = isset($_POST['Model']) ? $_POST['Model'] : '';
        $RAM = isset($_POST['RAM']) ? $_POST['RAM'] : '';
        $CPU = isset($_POST['CPU']) ? $_POST['CPU'] : '';
        $MAC_Address = isset($_POST['MAC_Address']) ? $_POST['MAC_Address'] : '';
        $Serial_Number = isset($_POST['Serial_Number']) ? $_POST['Serial_Number'] : '';
        $Product_Number = isset($_POST['Product_Number']) ? $_POST['Product_Number'] : '';
        $User = isset($_POST['User_ID']) ? $_POST['User_ID'] : '';
        $UserID = isset($_POST['ID']) ? $_POST['ID'] : '';
        $Location = isset($_POST['Location']) ? $_POST['Location'] : '';
        $Assigned = isset($_POST['Assigned']) ? $_POST['Assigned'] : '';
        $Faulty = isset($_POST['Faulty']) ? $_POST['Faulty'] : '';
        $Decommissioned = isset($_POST['Decommissioned']) ? $_POST['Decommissioned'] : '';
        $History = isset($_POST['History']) ? $_POST['History'] : '';
        
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE Laptops SET Asset_No = ?, Make = ?, Model = ?, RAM = ?, CPU = ?, MAC_Address = ?, Serial_Number = ?, Product_Number = ?, User_ID = ?, Location = ?, Assigned = ?, Faulty = ?, Decommissioned = ?, History = ? WHERE Asset_No = ?');
        $stmt->execute([$Asset_No, $Make, $Model, $RAM, $CPU, $MAC_Address, $Serial_Number, $Product_Number, $UserID, $Location, $Assigned, $Faulty, $Decommissioned, $History, $_GET['Asset_No']]);
        $msg = 'Updated Successfully!';

    }
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT `Asset_No`, `Make`, `Model`, `RAM`, `CPU`, `MAC_Address`, `Serial_Number`, `Product_Number`, `User_ID`, `Location`, `Assigned`, `Faulty`, `Decommissioned`, `History` FROM `laptops`s WHERE Asset_No = ?');
    $stmt->execute([$_GET['Asset_No']]);
    $laptops = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (!$laptops) {
        exit('Contact doesn\'t exist with that ID!');
    }
} else {
    exit('No ID specified!');
}



?>

<head>
           <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
           <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
           <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Glory:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  
           <script type="text/javascript"></script>
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {     
$('select[name="User"]').change(function(){
   var ID = $('option:selected', this).attr('ID');
   $("#ID").val(ID);
});

</script>


<?=template_header('Read')?>

<?php function get_id($con){
    $output = '';
    $functionsql = "SELECT * FROM customer";
    $functionresult = mysqli_query($con, $functionsql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($functionresult)){
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row["ID"].'">'.$row["Name"].'</option>';
    }
    
    return $output;

}

function show_id($con){
    $output2 = '';
    $functionsql2 = "SELECT ID FROM customer WHERE Name = '' ";
    $functionresult2 = mysqli_query($con, $functionsql2);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($functionresult2)){
        $output2 .= ''.$row["ID"].'';
    }
    
    return $output2;

}

 ?>

<div class="content update">
    <h2>Update Asset <?=$laptops['Asset_No']?></h2>
    <form action="update.php?Asset_No=<?=$laptops['Asset_No']?>" method="post">
        <label>Laptop Number</label><input type="Asset_No" name="Asset_No" value="<?=$laptops['Asset_No']?>" id="Asset_No" readonly>
        <label>Make</label><input type="Make" name="Make" value="<?=$laptops['Make']?>" id="Make" readonly>
        <label>Model</label><input type="Model" name="Model" value="<?=$laptops['Model']?>" id="Model" readonly>
        <label>RAM</label><input type="RAM" name="RAM" value="<?=$laptops['RAM']?>" id="RAM">
        <label>CPU</label><input type="CPU" name="CPU" value="<?=$laptops['CPU']?>" id="CPU" readonly>
        <label>MAC Address</label><input type="MAC_Address" name="MAC_Address" value="<?=$laptops['MAC_Address']?>" id="MAC_Address" >
        <label>Serial Number</label><input type="Serial_Number" name="Serial_Number" value="<?=$laptops['Serial_Number']?>" id="Serial_Number" readonly>
        <label>Product Number</label><input type="Product_Number" name="Product_Number" value="<?=$laptops['Product_Number']?>" id="Product_Number" readonly>


        <label>User</label> 
        <select name="User" id="User">
            <?php    
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo get_id($con);
                ?>">
                    <?php   
                    ?>
                </option>
            <?php 
            ?>
        </select>

        
        <label>ID</label>
        <input type="ID" name="ID" value='<?php echo show_id($con)?>' id="ID" >


    
    


        <label>Location</label><input type="Location" name="Location" value="<?=$laptops['Location']?>" id="Location" >
        <label>Assigned</label> 
        <select name="Assigned">
        <option <?php if($laptops['Assigned']=="Assigned") echo "selected"; ?> value="Assigned">Assigned</option>
        <option <?php if($laptops['Assigned']=="Returned") echo "selected"; ?> value="Returned">Returned</option>
        </select>
        <label>Faulty</label>    
        <select name="Faulty">
        <option <?php if($laptops['Faulty']=="Faulty") echo "selected"; ?> value="Faulty">Faulty</option>
        <option <?php if($laptops['Faulty']=="Working") echo "selected"; ?> value="Working">Working</option>
        </select>
        <label>Decommissioned</label>   
        <select name="Decommissioned">
        <option <?php if($laptops['Decommissioned']=="Decommissioned") echo "selected"; ?> value="Decommissioned">Decommissioned</option>
        <option <?php if($laptops['Decommissioned']=="Functioning") echo "selected"; ?> value="Functioning">Functioning</option>
        </select>
        <label>History</label><input type="History"  name="History" value="<?=$laptops['History']?>" id="History" rows="4">

        <input type="submit" value="Update">
        
    </form>



   
    <?php if ($msg): 
    
    ?>
    <p><?=$msg?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<?=template_footer()?>
```

Here is my laptops display page code "laptops.php"

```
<?php
include 'functions.php';
$pdo = pdo_connect_mysql();
$page = isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
$records_per_page = 5;


if (isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $cmd = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * 
                            FROM laptops 
                            WHERE Asset_No LIKE ? 
                            OR Faulty LIKE ? 
                            OR Decommissioned LIKE ? 
                            OR Assigned LIKE ? 
                            OR User LIKE ? 
                            OR MAC_Address LIKE ? 
                        ORDER BY Asset_No ASC');
    $cmd->execute(["%".$_GET['search']."%", "%".$_GET['search']."%", "%".$_GET['search']."%", "%".$_GET['search']."%", "%".$_GET['search']."%", "%".$_GET['search']."%"]);
    $laptop = $cmd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
} else {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM laptops ORDER BY Asset_No');
    $stmt->execute();
    $laptop = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $num_laptops = $pdo->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM laptops')->fetchColumn();
}
?>
<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Glory:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<?=template_header('Read')?>

<div class="content read">
    <h2>Laptops</h2>
    <a href="create.php" class="create-contact">Add Device</a>
    
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <input id="search" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Type here">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
    <br></br>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Asset_No</td>
                <td>Make</td>
                <td>Model</td>
                <td>RAM</td>
                <td>CPU</td>
                <td>MAC_Address</td>
                <td>Serial_Number</td>
                <td>Product_Number</td>
                <td>User</td>
                <td>Location</td>
                <td>Assigned</td>
                <td>Faulty</td>
                <td>Decommissioned</td>
                <td>History</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($laptop as $laptops): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$laptops['Asset_No']?></td>
                <td><?=$laptops['Make']?></td>
                <td><?=$laptops['Model']?></td>
                <td><?=$laptops['RAM']?></td>
                <td><?=$laptops['CPU']?></td>
                <td><?=$laptops['MAC_Address']?></td>
                <td><?=$laptops['Serial_Number']?></td>
                <td><?=$laptops['Product_Number']?></td>
                <td><?=$laptops['User_ID']?></td>
                <td><?=$laptops['Location']?></td>
                <td><?=$laptops['Assigned']?></td>
                <td><?=$laptops['Faulty']?></td>
                <td><?=$laptops['Decommissioned']?></td>
                <td><?=$laptops['History']?></td>
                <td class="actions">
                    <a href="update.php?Asset_No=<?=$laptops['Asset_No']?>" class="edit"><i class="fas fa-pen fa-xs"></i></a> 
                  <!--  <a href="delete.php?Asset_No=<?=$laptops['Asset_No']?>" class="trash"><i class="fas fa-trash fa-xs"></i></a>  -->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>


        <?php if ($page > 1): ?>
        <a href="read.php?page=<?=$page-1?>"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-left fa-sm"></i></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($page*$records_per_page < $num_laptops): ?>
        <a href="read.php?page=<?=$page+1?>"><i class="fas fa-angle-double-right fa-sm"></i></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>-->
</div>

<?=template_footer()?>
```

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: There are parts of your script that are open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: Is this a PHP question, a MySQL question, or an AJAX question? Usually, this can be checked through inspecting the requests: does the browser send the request as expected? Does PHP receive it as expected? Are the SQL querys built as expected?

Comment: I have updated my code for the 'update.php' page, as I have now managed to get all the Customer.Name values into the Select element. But I am not too sure how I go about returning the Customer.ID value of the selected Customer.Name, into my input field.